# Finding the asymptotic behaviour of an integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I want to find the full asymptotic behaviour of the integral

$$I = \int_1^\infty (t^2-1)^{-1/2}e^{-xt}\,{\rm d}t$$

at $x\to\infty$. So firstly we note that the integrand doesn't exist at $t=1$ so we must attempt to remove the "singularity". Letting $t=\cosh{(u)}$ gives

$$I = \int_0^\infty e^{-x\cosh{u}}\,{\rm d}u$$

then recall that

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\qquad \cosh{x}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2m}}{(2m)!}$$

which both converge for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Using these we find that

$$I=\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{u^{2m}}{(2m)!}\right)^n\,{\rm d}x$$

Now how would I progress?

Comment: Note that this integral is equal to $K_0(x)$ in case you didn't know.  You can also set $t=\cosh{u}$ to simplify matters.

Comment: @RonGordon I have used what you have said and attempted to go further - not sure if I've gone the correct route however since it seems very complicated.

Comment: You probably should apply Watson's Lemma.

Comment: @RonGordon I haven't been taught Watson's lemma in my lecture course so I doubt that's the intended method

Comment: Well, if you are looking for a full asymptotic expansion...I am sorry, you want Laplace's method which I illustrated in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub $t=\cosh{u}$; then

$$I(x) = \int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{-x \cosh{u}} $$

Apply Laplace's method.  Note that, while

$$\cosh{u} = 1 + \frac{u^2}{2!} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{u^{2 k}}{(2 k)!} $$

we Taylor expand the exponential only for the higher order terms in the sum in the limit as $x \to \infty$.  Thus, for example, to order $2 N$:

$$I(x) = e^{-x} \int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{-x u^2/2} \left [1+ a_4 u^4 + a_6 u^6 + \cdots + O(u^{2 N}) \right ] $$

Now, the coefficients $a_4$, $a_6$, and so on would need to be computed via Taylor expansion of the exponential of the above sum.  Use the fact that

$$\int_0^{\infty} du \, u^{2 k} e^{-x u^2/2} = \frac12 \left (\frac{2}{x} \right )^{k+1/2} \Gamma \left ( k+\frac12 \right ) $$

and you can derive the full asymptotic expansion to as many terms as you need.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{I \equiv \int_{1}^{\infty}\pars{t^{2} - 1}^{-1/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t:\ ?}$.

I'll 'remove' the integrable singularity at $\ds{t = 1}$. Namely, $\ds{t \equiv 1 + \xi^{2}}$:
\begin{align}
I & \equiv \int_{1}^{\infty}\pars{t^{2} - 1}^{-1/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t =
2\expo{-x}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x\xi^{2}} \over \root{\xi^{2} + 2}}\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm] &=
\root{2}\expo{-x}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\xi^{2}}
\exp\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over 2}\,\xi^{2}}}\,\dd\xi
\end{align}

---

When $\ds{x \to \infty}$, the 'main contribution' to the integral comes from $\ds{\xi \gtrsim 0}$ such that ( by means of the *Laplace Method* ):
\begin{align}
I & =
\root{2}\expo{-x}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\xi^{2}}
\bracks{1 - {1 \over 4}\,\xi^{2} + {3 \over 32}\,\xi^{4} - {5 \over 228}\,\xi^{6} + \mrm{O}\pars{\xi^{8}}}\,\dd\xi
\end{align}

---

For instance, up to $\ds{\large\color{#f00}{3}}$ *terms*
$\ds{\pars{~\mbox{note that}\ \int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\xi^{2}}\xi^{\mu}\,\dd\xi = {\Gamma\pars{\bracks{\mu + 1}/2} \over 2x^{\pars{\mu + 1}/2}}~}}$:
\begin{align}
I & \equiv \int_{1}^{\infty}\pars{t^{2} - 1}^{-1/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t \sim
{\root{2} \over 2}\expo{-x}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over x^{1/2}} -
{1 \over 4}\,{\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over x^{3/2}} +
{3 \over 32}\,{\Gamma\pars{5/2} \over x^{5/2}}}\
\mbox{as}\ x \to \infty
\\[5mm]
I & \equiv \int_{1}^{\infty}\pars{t^{2} - 1}^{-1/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t\,\,\,
\bbx{\ds{\sim \root{\pi \over 2}\expo{-x}\pars{{1 \over x^{1/2}} -
{1 \over 8x^{3/2}} + {9 \over 128x^{5/2}}}\
\mbox{as}\ x \to \infty}}
\end{align}